# How to set up a LiveCycle ES4 Reverse Proxy for external users?

Tags: pdf-generation, reverse-proxy, livecycle

We have LiveCycle ES4 SP1 configured and running on WebSphere v8.5 and Windows 2008 R2.  We're primarily using the application for end user PDF conversion services at this point.  However, 10% of our users are outside our networks and without a VPN.

Authentication is done via LDAP-AD 2008 synchronization on the internal network.  What is involved in setting up a reverse proxy service for the PDF conversion functionality?  Is there any documentation available online that I can reference?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the following links.  You can easily do this with IIS, Apache, or by using the AEM Dispatcher.  I'll suggest looking at the following links.

- http://blogs.adobe.com/livecycle/2009/04/fronting_livecyclejboss_with_a.html
- http://blogs.adobe.com/cguerrero/2010/10/27/configuring-a-reverse-proxy-with-apache-that-handles-https-connections/
- http://blogs.adobe.com/livecycle/2011/03/configuring-iis-7-5-to-load-balance-a-livecycle-cluster.html
- https://www.adobeaemcloud.com/content/companies/public/adobe/dispatcher/dispatcher.html

Most of those links will allow you to work through it.  I recently did this for IIS using ARR and followed these steps:

- Open Server Manager under Administrative Tools
- Choose Roles
- Click Add Roles, then select Web Server (IIS)
- Make sure “Directory Browsing” is unchecked (it is checked by default)
- Check “HTTP Redirection”
- Click Install
- Re-start the server
- Download ARR 3.0 Standalone from http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/A/4/2A4DFCD2-E577-422C-8435-0D8F5D9085E8/ARRv3_setup_amd64_en-us.EXE
- Double click on the file that was just downloaded
- Click Yes
- Click Yes
- Click OK
- Open the IIS Manager under Administrative Tools
- Expand the local server
- Click on Server Farms in the left panel
- Click on Create Server Farm on the right
- Specify a name such as AEM
- Click Next
- Enter the internal IP or hostname of the AEM server.
- Click Add
- Click Finish
- Click Yes
- Double click on the new server farm
- Double click Caching
- Ensure that Query String Support is set to Include query string
- Click Apply
- Click on the server farm again
- Double click on Routing Rules
- Ensure that Use URL Rewrite to inspect incoming requests is selected
- Click Apply if necessary
- Click on the server farm again
- Double click on Server Affinity
- Select Client Affinity and click Apply if needed
- Ensure that port 80 and 443 are opened on the App Servers firewall
- Add the hostname of the IIS/ARR/Web Server to the allowed referrer list
- Restart JBoss
- Load the adminui via the Web Servers external hostname (http://yourdomain.com/adminui)